# pylab backend from cmd prompt?

Tags: enthought

I've run into an issue...
First, I've been trying (with little success yet) of 'packaging' a Canopy python file into an .exe.  I'm trying to make a 'simple' way to run our program(s) for our client.

With those issues, I thought I'd make a .cmd file with 'python myprog.py' in it. Well, it fires up my code without having the Canopy environment there to confuse my end-users, BUT, it appears that the PyLab backend isn't Qt4, as the screen appears quite a bit different, and the actual program doesn't quite run the same :(

Is there some way to tell Canopy that when I start a program using 'python xxx.py' that it should be using the Qt4 package?  I've looked at the Preferences for Canopy, and both the Notebook tab and the Python tab have the PyLab backend set to Interactive (Qt4)?  If I can find that and get my panels to look the same as in the Canopy environment, I'll see if the rest of the program straightens out too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steve, if you wish you can hard-code this into your program, but as a quick solution, precede your `python` call with:

```
set ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4
```

Comment: Excellent...now the program looks the same as in the Canopy editor :).  I do still have an issue though--the program doesn't 'act' the same :(.  For example, when I start up inside of Canopy, it automatically reads a datafile, and it doesn't when I start from the command prompt.  In fact, if I use m program's buttons to read the datafile, it doesn't appear to be reading at all, and I get no python errors/messages in the cmd window (ie. none of the variables on my screen get updated with values from the datafile that I try to read).  Any ideas on where I should start tracking that down?

Comment: Not enough detail to speculate. Try writing a minimal script that should open the datafile, and see where the behavior is different. Perhaps the first place to look is whether you are assuming that the data file is in the current directory and/or the same directory as the script itself. In general you cannot assume that these are the same, though depending on your settings, Canopy may make them be the same. Look at the value of `__file__` in your script.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...I'll start there.